# SATA III 6Gb/s, is that 6gbit/sec per device, or for the entire controller?

Tags: raid, sata

If I have (12) SSD drives in a RAID6, will the max connection speed of each drive be 6Gbps, or is that for the entire controller?

Answer (score 8):

The 6gbs specification is per channel. So depending on the controller it can be per drive, yes.
However your controller will not manage the theoretical maximum  speed of 12 combined disks in raid 6.